# how you are using mustache js and link

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I try inside this code to display the value `{{app}}` and `{{vendor}}` .
Do you have and idea ?
for this, it's ok

```
  <td>{{title}}</td>
  <td>{{vendor}}</td>
```

but inside this element does'nt work

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . OSCOM::link('index.php', 'index.php?A&{{app}}\{{vendor}}') . '">' . HTML::image($OSCOM_Template->getImageDirectory() . '/icons/edit.gif', OSCOM::getDef('image_edit')) . '</a>'; ?>
```

Tk

json example :

```
{
 "title":   "BestSelling App",
 "app": "BestSelling",
 "vendor":"BestSelling"
}
```

data:

```
 <script id="appInstalledTableEntry" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <tr>
      <td>{{title}}</td>
      <td>{{vendor}}</td>
      <td class="text-md-right">{{version}}</td>
      <td class="text-md-right action"><?php echo '<a href="' . OSCOM::link('index.php', 'index.php?A&{{app}}\{{vendor}}') . '">' . HTML::image($OSCOM_Template->getImageDirectory() . '/icons/edit.gif', OSCOM::getDef('image_edit')) . '</a>'; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </script>
```

Comment: This is probably a sequencing issue. Are you rendering the mustache template after the document is ready?

Comment: The script <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.1/mustache.min.js"></script> is inserted at the bottom of the page. but {{title}} works fine,  the pb come '' : 'index.php?A&{{app}}\{{vendor}}'

Comment: I didn't mean your declaration. Please update your question with how you are using `Mustache.render();`.